# Can someone show me how to use command in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, networking

I would like someone to help me and guide me how to use Ubuntu from command line.

Comment: You can start with [Command line How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandlineHowto).

Answer (score 1):

Your question provides insufficient information.
What do you want to use the commands for?

If you are looking to familiarize yourself with terminal, these guides will help you get started:

- [Using The Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)
- [Command line - How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandlineHowto)